# Schematic pins shifted over on Altium 16

Tags: altium, pins

I am coming across an issue where Altium is shifting pin names to the left. When I updated from 15 to 16, I have noticed the issue come up. When generating the schematic from 16 to 17, the issues go away. No, I did not shift the pin names like that when creating the parts. Comparison between 16 and 17 preferences are basically the same. I have been using 17 to generate the schematic, however, I want to stick to 16 right now. Please look at the examples below. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?   [image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the "Render Text with GDI+"
Go to: DXP -> Preferences -> Schematic -> General

Should work;-)